# Orientational Canny Edge Detection

Tags: matlab, image-processing, canny-operator

I want to detect edges using Canny method. In the end I want two edge maps: 1 for horizontal 1 for vertical direction.

In MATLAB this can be achieved by using Sobel or Prewitt operators with an extra direction argument, but for Canny we do not have this option.

```
E = edge(I,'Sobel','horizontal')
```

Any idea how to extract both horizontal and vertical edges, separately, by using Canny?

Comment: You should first read how work a canny edge algorithm... A canny edge detection IS bidirectionnal, it make no sense to extract horizontal or vertical edges.

Comment: [how work a canny edge detection](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html#steps)

Comment: @obchardon from the link you provided:  "The direction is rounded to one of four possible angles (namely 0, 45, 90 or 135)" So I am assuming those are for vertical, horizontal, diagonal-left, diagonal-right. I am just interested in vertical and horizontal ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way using the built in [`edge`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html) function. However, Canny edge detection uses the angles from the [Sobel Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator). It is very easy to reproduce these values.

1. Start with an image, I'll use a built in demo image.

   ```
   A = im2double(rgb2gray(imread('peppers.png')));
   ```
2. Get the Canny edges

   ```
   A_canny = edge(A, 'Canny');
   ```
3. Sobel Operator -- We can't use the built in implementation (`edge(A_filter, 'Sobel')`), because we want the edge angles, not just the edge locations, so we implement our own operator.

   a. Gaussian filter. This is a preprocessing step for Canny, so we should probably reproduce it here

   ```
   A_filter = imgaussfilt(A);
   ```

   b. Convolution to find oriented gradients

   ```
   %These filters measure the difference in values between vertically or horizontally adjacent pixels. 
   %Effectively, this finds vertical and horizontal gradients.
   vertical_filter = [-1 0 1; -2 0 2; -1 0 1];
   horizontal_filter = [-1 -2 -1; 0 0 0; 1 2 1];
   A_vertical = conv2(A_filter, vertical_filter, 'same');
   A_horizontal = conv2(A_filter, horizontal_filter, 'same');
   ```

   c. Calculate the angles

   ```
   A_angle = arctan(A_vertical./A_horizontal);
   ```
4. Get the angle values at the edge locations

   ```
   A_canny_angles = nan(size(A));
   A_canny_angles(A_canny) = A_angle(A_canny);
   ```
5. Choose the angles that you are interested in

   ```
   angle_tolerance = 22.5/180*pi;
   target_angle = 0;
   A_target_angle = A_canny_angles >= target_angle*pi/180 - angle_tolerance & ...
       A_canny_angles<= target_angle*pi/180 + angle_tolerance;
   ```

So if I'm looking for horizontal lines, my target angle would be zero. The image below illustrates steps 1, 2, 4 and 5. The final result of the extracted horizontal lines is shown in the bottom right. You can see that they are not exactly horizontal because I used such a large angle tolerance window. This is a tunable parameter depending on how exactly you want to hit your target angle.

[image: Result]